# Updating varchar to longtext leads to data loss

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, update

I run a number of MySQL servers for my Java application. I have a table that looks like this:

```
 +---------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
 | Field         | Type           | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
 +---------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
 | app_xid       | varchar(200)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 | attr_key      | varchar(200)   | NO   | PRI |         |       |
 | entry_xid     | varchar(200)   | NO   | PRI |         |       |
 | entry_version | int(11)        | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
 | date_value    | datetime       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 | int_value     | int(11)        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 | string_value  | varchar(10000) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
 | clob_value    | longtext       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 | blob_value    | blob           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 +---------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Now, I have some data that are in the `string_value` column and I want them in the `clob_value` column.

Initially the data looks like this:

```
************** 65. row *************
string_value: [a2:hoj]   
clob_value: NULL
attr_key: member
************** 66. row *************
string_value: [a2:hoj]   
clob_value: NULL
attr_key: member
```

Now I run this command:

```
update attribute
set clob_value=string_value,
    string_value=null
where string_value is not null
  and clob_value is null
  and attr_key in ('member');
```

I would expect that the resulting values to be

```
string_value: NULL
clob_value:  [a2:hoj]
attr_key: member
```

but on 4 out of my 35 servers they end up being

```
string_value: NULL
clob_value: 
attr_key: member
```

where the nothing in the `clob_value` is actually 8 characters with ASCII value 0.

If I instead of that update run this one:

```
update attribute
set clob_value=string_value
where string_value is not null
  and clob_value is null
  and attr_key in ('member');
```

i.e. I leave out the setting of `string_value` to null, the result is the expected

```
string_value: [a2:hoj]
clob_value:  [a2:hoj]
attr_key: member
```

I'm puzzled by this behavior, could someone help?

MySQL version info:

> mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.44, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2

The create table of the table is

```
CREATE TABLE `attribute` (
   `app_xid` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `attr_key` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `entry_xid` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `entry_version` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `date_value` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `int_value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `string_value` varchar(10000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `clob_value` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
   `blob_value` blob,
   PRIMARY KEY (`entry_xid`,`entry_version`,`attr_key`),
   KEY `attribute_string_value_idx` (`string_value`(30)),
   CONSTRAINT`attr_to_entry` FOREIGN KEY (`entry_xid`, `entry_version`)
                             REFERENCES `entry` (`entry_xid`, `entry_version`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Generally not a good idea to put zero-bytes in `TEXT` or `CHAR` type columns.  `BLOB` and `BINARY` are less likely to mangle them.

Comment: I do not want to store zero-bytes. They just appear there for no obvious reason.

Comment: How did you discover the existence of the zero-bytes?

Comment: first of all by select char_length(clob_value) ..., which returned the correct non-zero lengths. Then I did things like ord(clob_value) and ascii(clob_value), which return a zero. I tried a few locate('a',clob_value) selects to make sure that characters are not present and just somehow invisible.

Comment: `HEX(clob_value)` is another way.  I find `HEX` to be quite definitive.